# Error using nth-child

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this:

```css
a {
    display:table;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:first-child {
    color:#00FF00; /* green */
}

a:nth-child(3) {     
    color:#FF0000; /* red */
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Google<a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google<a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google<a>
```

Question:
Why is the second "Google" red and not the third? Whats happening here?

Comment: Close the `<a>` tag...

Comment: Has [validating your html](https://validator.w3.org/) become unfashionable? When I was young...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Thanks for the validator link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

close the achor tag

HTML

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/z569bm6w/

Comment: Sure, can you please upvote this question? I got two downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

close `</a>`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


a {

    display:block;
}
a:hover {

 text-decoration:none;

}

a:first-child {
 color:#00FF00;
}
a:nth-child(3) {     
 color:#FF0000;      
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can check this on : https://jsfiddle.net/4k5f03yq/

It can't find the nth-child. Because a tag not close.
```